# Not able to get the data from mysql database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I wrote this code and I ran it on my browser, I get the output as 'not executed'.

I use PHP 5.3 version.

I have already checked out a lot of posts but I seem to figure this error out. 
and I also tried to use `mysqli` functions but that also won't work. Please help me figure this out please.

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';
$query="SELECT * FROM 'masu'";

if($is_query_run=mysql_query($query))
{
    echo 'Query executed';
    while($query_execute=mysql_fetch_array($is_query_run))
    {
         echo "excuted";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "not executed";
}
?>
```

The code for connect.php is here :

```
<?php
$mysql_host='localhost';
$mysql_user='root';
$mysql_password='masu';
$con=mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user,$mysql_password);
if(!@mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user,$mysql_password))
{
    die('Cannot connect to database');
}
else
{
    if(@mysql_select_db('masudha'))
    {
    //  echo 'connection success with masu';
    }
    else
    {
        die('cannot connect to database');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Get rid of error suppression. Don't use `mysql_`. You only use quotes on strings, columns/tables are not strings.

Comment: can you not just have `if (mysql_query($query)) {` as this would mean `if true`

Comment: You should be switching to mysqli urgently anyway, so you can start to move away from these insecure functions, and the out-of-support version of PHP you're using. So please show us the `mysqli`  code you tried, and we can help you fix that instead.

Comment: P.S. Before you show us the new code, remove any error suppression (i.e. remove `@`s before function names) and also ensure you have PHP set to log errors, and mysqli set to throw exceptions when SQL errors occur. See here for guidance: https://stackify.com/php-error-logs-guide/ (php error logging/reporting)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14578644/5947043 (mysqli exception handling)

Comment: Using `mysql_connect` twice also generates two connections for every load.

Comment: "I use PHP 5.3 version." Why?

Comment: Just remove the quotes from the table name. There isn't anything in it that mysql will complain about. Ticks are usually used in place of quotes, for too many reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Use Backticks for tablenames and columnnames

Single quotes are only valid for strings

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `masu`";
```

For [more Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. This solution helped me! backticks did work.